# Filed download and install Go modules dlv & gopls in VSCode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, gopls, dlv

When i run my Go code in VSCode i needed install some modules. All modules normal downloaded and installing but 2 moduled (dlv & gopls) filed.

```
Tools environment: GOPATH=/home/user/project
Installing 2 tools at /home/user/project/bin in module mode.
  dlv
  gopls

Installing github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest FAILED
{
 "killed": false,
 "code": 1,
 "signal": null,
 "cmd": "/usr/local/go/bin/go install -v github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest",
 "stdout": "",
 "stderr": "go: downloading golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20220908164124-27713097b956\n../pkg/mod/github.com/sirupsen/logrus@v1.6.0/terminal_check_unix.go:6:8: golang.org/x/sys@v0.0.0-20220908164124-27713097b956: read \"https:/proxy.golang.org/@v/v0.0.0-20220908164124-27713097b956.zip\": read tcp 192.168.1.125:37454->209.85.233.141:443: read: connection reset by peer\n"
}
Installing golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest FAILED
{
 "killed": false,
 "code": 1,
 "signal": null,
 "cmd": "/usr/local/go/bin/go install -v golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest",
 "stdout": "",
 "stderr": "go: downloading golang.org/x/sys v0.2.0\n../pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.3.1-0.20221213193459-ca17b2c27ca8/go/packages/external.go:15:2: golang.org/x/sys@v0.2.0: read \"https:/proxy.golang.org/@v/v0.2.0.zip\": read tcp 192.168.1.125:53838->142.250.185.209:443: read: connection reset by peer\n"
}

2 tools failed to install.

dlv: failed to install dlv(github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest): Error: Command failed: /usr/local/go/bin/go install -v github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest
go: downloading golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20220908164124-27713097b956
../pkg/mod/github.com/sirupsen/logrus@v1.6.0/terminal_check_unix.go:6:8: golang.org/x/sys@v0.0.0-20220908164124-27713097b956: read "https:/proxy.golang.org/@v/v0.0.0-20220908164124-27713097b956.zip": read tcp 192.168.1.125:37454->209.85.233.141:443: read: connection reset by peer
 
gopls: failed to install gopls(golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest): Error: Command failed: /usr/local/go/bin/go install -v golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest
go: downloading golang.org/x/sys v0.2.0
../pkg/mod/golang.org/x/tools@v0.3.1-0.20221213193459-ca17b2c27ca8/go/packages/external.go:15:2: golang.org/x/sys@v0.2.0: read "https:/proxy.golang.org/@v/v0.2.0.zip": read tcp 192.168.1.125:53838->142.250.185.209:443: read: connection reset by peer
```

In the terminal the code builds fine. I think the problem is in VSCode, but googling didn't turn up anything.